# Background image fullscreen

Tags: html, css, image, web

So I am  trying to create a webpage that has two `div` elements. In one, an image. In the second, an `background-color`. There's one problem though. The image does not reach to the edge of the screen! How can I do this? I don't want to use the definers for the width, I want it to scale nice on everything.

```html
<head>
        <title>Derr</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
            }
            .fadein {
                background-image: url("img.bmp");
                height: 549px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fadein">
            <br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Using Chrome.

Comment: try adding: `background-size: cover;` and removing the height property for the image.

Comment: nope. there's supposed to be nothing IN the `div`, so this is a nogo.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it this way

```css
   body{
     margin:0px;
   } 
    
    .fadein{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="fadein">
           
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: nope there's still white bars on the sides of the page.

Comment: did you give the body 'margin: 0px' ? because the code i gave you fills everything out

Comment: no there's still small white bars all around the page

Comment: and running the snippet code in "full page" you see the white bars to?

Comment: even in fullscreen

Comment: Then the problem comes from your browser because the code works

Comment: \_(シ)_/ by the way, what _are_ you using

Comment: Google chrome / Firefox / IE / Opera / Safari but for the moment Chrome